# Add jars to Ibm Websphere Portal Server with out restarting the server

Tags: websphere, websphere-portal

I have multiple applications that share common jars, so I decided to put them in the shared library and add a reference to all the applications.

Now the problem is that when I make a change in one of the jars and put them back I have to re start the server.

The weird thing is that I have to do that on my local system and not on the shared server, i was trying to find the setting that will allow me to upload the jar and see the effect with out restarting the server.

One of the blogs says it it not possible but on the shared server it happens so I am sure it is definitely possible.

Please advice what can be done here.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you've configured the shared library to be a part of the server's classpath. Any JARs on the server classpath are only loaded once on server startup. Changes to these JARs require a full server restart.

Libraries that are added to the application's classpath can be reloaded dynamically. The application will still need to restart when the JAR gets changed but that's a much lighter operation and WAS will often automatically detect a file system change and restart the affected applications.

Check how you've configured your shared library to make sure it's being loaded on the application classpath.